# I want a function to only be evaluated when the attribute is accessed

Tags: javascript

I have videos on my page that make a server call for an ad when played. When my page loads, I try to to rewrite the URL and add parameters. To do this I set the URL to a function like this `player.URL = addParams()` where addParams() returns the new URL as a string. The problem is that the function evaluates when the page loads instead of when I make the video call. Is there anyway to only evaluate the function when the URL is accessed? This is done is Javascript.

Comment: what type is player?  Where/when is URL assigned?

Comment: ```player.URL = () => addParams()``` perhaps

Comment: Or just `player.URL = addParams` (without parentheses).